# Use datatable ajax response data to set custom label value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

I have used [server-side processing data table](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html).

Here is my datatable configuration:

```
var table = $("#job-table").DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "<?php echo url('/getJobs');?>",
        "type": "POST",
        "data": function (d) {
            d.connection = connectionArray,
            d.company = companyArray,
            d.type = typeArray
        }
    },
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "columns": [
        { "data": "id" },
        { "data": "job_id" },
        { "data": "type" },
        { "data": "connection_id" },
        { "data": "company_id" },
        { "data": "message" },
        { "data": "total_completion_time" },
        { "data": "date" },
        { "data": "start_time" },
        { "data": "end_time" },
        { "data": "error_time" }
    ],
    "info":     false,
    "searching": false,
    "bLengthChange": false
});
```

In this datatable ajax response I have passed some another data which I am gonna use to set custom label value.

Right now, I am using same ajax call to set label value. There are two calls one is of datatable and another call for setting label. Both time I am calling same API. but want to know how can I avoid second ajax call?
Is there any way to use data-table `ajax` call response to set custom label value?

Comment: "*Some another data*" is a little bit vague. `dataSrc: function(json) { $('#label').html( json.someAnotherData ); return json }` could perhaps give you a hint ...?

Comment: No not working! :(
I return one parameter in datatable response i.e "avg_number_of_completion" at "data" level
like - I have used data inside column I want to use avg_number_of_completion to set label

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar.  I used the dataFilter callback to handle it.

so given HTML:

```
    <input id="txtOne"/>
    <input id="txtTwo"/>
    <table id="job-table" class="display"></table>
```

Serverside code is returning a JSON Serialized object that looks like:

```
{ ValueOne: "some data",
  ValueTwo: "Some more data",
  data: [array of data for the table] }
```

My table definition looks like (notice the dataFilter section):

```
var table = $("#job-table").DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "<?php echo url('/getJobs');?>",
        "type": "POST",
        "data": function (d) {
            d.connection = connectionArray,
            d.company = companyArray,
            d.type = typeArray
        },
        // I added this section. It is called before the success callback 
        // You will have to figure out your parsing at this point because 
        // each configuration is different so I just put how mine is.

        dataFilter: function(response){
            var temp = JSON.parse(response);
            $("#txtOne").val(temp.ValueOne);
            $("#txtTwo").val(temp.ValueTwo);


            return response;

        }
    },
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "columns": [
        { "data": "id" },
        { "data": "job_id" },
        { "data": "type" },
        { "data": "connection_id" },
        { "data": "company_id" },
        { "data": "message" },
        { "data": "total_completion_time" },
        { "data": "date" },
        { "data": "start_time" },
        { "data": "end_time" },
        { "data": "error_time" }
    ],
    "info": false,
    "searching": false,
    "bLengthChange": false
});
```